# SQL Alchemy - Using literal on select

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
t1 = aliased(XXXXX, name='T1')
t2 = aliased(YYYYY, name='T2')
t3 = aliased(ZZZZZ, name='T3')

s1 = select([t1.std_cpf,
             t1.email,
             t1.gender,
             t1.id,
             t1.birth_date,
             literal_column("'zero'")
             ])

s2 = select([t2.std_cpf,
             t2.email,
             t2.gender,
             t2.id,
             t2.birth_date,
             literal_column("'zero'")
             ])

s3 = select([t3.std_cpf,
             t3.email,
             t3.gender,
             t3.id,
             t3.birth_date,
             literal_column("'zero'")
             ])

q = sqlalchemy.sql.expression.union(s1, s2, s3).alias('customer')
```

Error:

> LINE 1: ...customer.birth_date AS customer_birth_date, customer.'zero'

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the label for the literal_column

```
s1 = select([t1.std_cpf,
             t1.email,
             t1.gender,
             t1.id,
             t1.birth_date,
             literal_column("'zero'").label('zero')
             ])
```